# rollback IO action

Tags: haskell, io-monad

I have a very simple abstraction for dealing with a sequence of IO actions which can be rolled back (to some extent), i.e. if an action writes a file, then rollback would be deleting this file or if an action creates a directory tree, pruning it would be the rollback, etc.

```
data IOAction = IOAction {
  execute  :: IO (),
  rollback :: IO ()
}

executeAll :: [IOAction] -> IO ()
executeAll [] = return ()
executeAll (a : as) = do
  execute a
  executeAll as `catch` rollbackAndRethrow
  where
    rollbackAndRethrow :: SomeException -> IO ()
    rollbackAndRethrow e = rollback a >> throw e
```

It does pretty much what I want, but I have a strong hunch that there are more composable and more reliable (in the sense of exception handling) ways to do it. So my question is could I use, say, a known monad transformer from some library to implement the same idea?

Having something like

```
writeFilesAtomically :: CanRollbackT IO ()
writeFilesAtomically = do
  a1 <- (writeFile a str1) `orRollback` removeFile a
  a2 <- (writeFile x str2) `orRollback` removeFile x
  ....
```

would be more convenient than the current solution.

Comment: A monad like this would look similar to [ResourceT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/resourcet-1.1.7.3/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Resource.html):  "a modified ReaderT monad transformer holding onto a mutable reference to all of the release actions still remaining to be performed". The difference is that the cleanup actions would only be performed in case of error. Given that `ResourceT` gives the user access to its [internal state](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/resourcet-1.1.7.3/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Resource.html#g:9) perhaps it could serve as the base of a `RollbackT` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This looks very much like a `WriterT` monad combined with `ExceptT`. You could probably do something like this:

```
orRollback action rollaction = do
    eres <- liftIO $ try action 
    case eres of
       Right res -> do
          tell [rollaction]
          return res
       Left (e :: SomeException) -> throwE e
```

And then call it like:

```
runMyComputation computation = do
   (res, rolls) <- runWriterT $ runExceptT $ computation
   case res of
       Right r -> return r
       Left e -> do
           sequence_ (reverse rolls) -- Handle errors in rollbacks?
           throwIO e
```

I didn't test it, but the idea should work. You might probably need some better monoid than `[]` if you are going to see exceptions often.

This doesn't quite compose as you cannot do `onRollback` on non-IO actions. But that might be perfectly OK.

Comment: Removing rollback actions once something succeeds seems annoying with this approach; could you comment on how to do that briefly?

Comment: I don't understand; if the computation succeeds, the rollback list is ignored.

Comment: Shouldn't the tell [rollaction] be in the Left case?